# aws: missing credentials in config when using systemd

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, systemd

I'm trying to deploy a small Node.js server to a Linux EC2 on AWS. This server uses the AWS JavaScript SDK. The `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config` are properly filled out. Everything works when I run the server by `node index.js` or `npm start`, but if I run it using `systemd`, I get the following response:

```
{ message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
retryable: false,
time: 2018-07-23T20:12:59.057Z,
code: 'CredentialsError' }
```

Comment: Who is the process running as?  You'll need the credentials set for **that** user (root?).

Comment: By `systemd`, I presume you mean via a `.service` file. Unless you set a user manually in those, it will run as root. This also implies that `~` becomes `/root` instead of your home dir, thus the files can no longer be located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some systems ~ becomes / when run from a service. This means the path is /.aws/credentials. For your system try copying "~/.aws" to "/root/.aws". Then try copying to "/.aws". One of these will work.

You can also use a json file and specify that when creating your client.

Create the file "/mysite/aws_config.json" with the following contents:

```
{
    "accessKeyId":     "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
    "secretAccessKey": "YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", 
    "region":          "YOUR_REGION"
}
```

Then load the credentials with this statement:

```
AWS.config.loadFromPath('/mysite/aws_config.json');
```

This way you can keep your site's configuration in one directory.

There are many methods to specify credentials. The AWS documentation for node.js SDK has lots more.

Comment: Just copying to /root/.aws did the trick --- I'm on Ubuntu 1604